# htaccess redirect with parameters to an subfolder?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I searched for a htaccess solution to redirect from this url :

https://www.example.com/my/search?areastate=sg

to

https://www.example.com/my/search2?state=sg

I found this, but it doesn't seem to work with subfolders:

```
RewriteRule ^search  /my/search2 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work" ? Does it redirect your URL to an unexpected location?